# How to show loader icon in custom div magento 2

Tags: magento2, loader

how to show non stop loader icon in custom div when page is starting work

```
<div id="loader-example">
    <h3>Block</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos itaque numquam placeat quam recusandae velit voluptas. Ad architecto asperiores eos eveniet id nostrum officiis saepe soluta totam voluptate! Debitis, quibusdam.
</div>
```

i'm trying this from magento 2 docs

```
<div id="loader-example" data-mage-init='{"loader": { "icon":"<?=$imagePath;?>"}}'>
    <h3>Block</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos itaque numquam placeat quam recusandae velit voluptas. Ad architecto asperiores eos eveniet id nostrum officiis saepe soluta totam voluptate! Debitis, quibusdam.
</div>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'loader', 'domReady!'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#loader-example').trigger('processStart');
    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try loader widget of magento?

If not you can try this for custom your loader which you want
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html

Comment: <div id="loader-example" data-mage-init='{"loader": { "icon": "{store URL}/static/{static version}/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"}}'>
    <h3>Block</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos itaque numquam placeat quam recusandae velit voluptas. Ad architecto asperiores eos eveniet id nostrum officiis saepe soluta totam voluptate! Debitis, quibusdam.
</div>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'loader', 'domReady!'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#loader-example').trigger('processStart');
});
</script>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: edit my answer))

Comment: Did you face any error when inspect?

Comment: Did you try simple way <script>
require(['jquery', 'loader'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $('#example').loader({
        icon: 'path to icon'
    });
});
</script>

Comment: no errors. Yes try but not work again.

Comment: <div id="loader-example" data-mage-init='{"loader": { "icon":"<?=$imagePath;?>"}}'>
    <h3>Block</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos itaque numquam placeat quam recusandae velit voluptas. Ad architecto asperiores eos eveniet id nostrum officiis saepe soluta totam voluptate! Debitis, quibusdam.
</div>
<script> require(['jquery', 'loader'], function ($) { 'use strict'; $('#loader-example').loader({ icon: '<?=$imagePath;?>' }); }); </script>

Answer (score 2):

In any .phtml file :

```
<div id="loader-example">
<h3>Block</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos itaque numquam placeat quam recusandae velit voluptas. Ad architecto asperiores eos eveniet id nostrum officiis saepe soluta totam voluptate! Debitis, quibusdam.
</div>

<script>
require(['jquery', 'loader'], function ($) {
    // To initialize loader
    $('#loader-example').loader({
        icon: "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-2.gif')); ?>"
    });

    // To enable loader
    $('#loader-example').loader('show');

    // To disable loader
    // $('#loader-example').loader('hide');
});
</script>
```

Then, in your .less file :

```
#loader-example {
    position: relative;

    .loading-mask {
        position: absolute;

        img {
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
}
```